# Overload resolution for two functions taking parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, reference, variadic-templates

Please consider the following two overloads:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void f(std::vector<T>&& v, Args&& ...args)
{
    std::cout << "f taking a vector + parameter pack\n";
}

template<typename ...Args>
void f(Args&& ...args)
{
    std::cout << "f taking a parameter pack\n";
}
```

Now, for the following fragment the expected overload is chosen:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
f(std::move(v), 3.0);
```

(outputs: *f taking a vector + parameter pack*)

For the following case, the second overload is chosen:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
f(v, 3.0);
```

(outputs: *f taking a parameter pack*)

<del>The universal reference vector parameter binds to an lvalue reference as well</del>, so why is it that the overload with just the parameter pack is being favored in this case? *Update:* see the accepted answer, the assumption that the vector parameter is a universal/forwarding reference is wrong.

Comment: `std::vector<T>&&` is not a universal reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The universal reference vector parameter binds to an lvalue reference as well

No, it's not a [universal reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

> 4) If **P** is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called "forwarding reference"), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to **A** is used in place of **A** for deduction (Note: this is the basis for the action of [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) Note: in [class template deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction), template parameter of a class template is never a forwarding reference (since C++17)):

So for

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void f(std::vector<T>&& v, Args&& ...args)
```

note that `v` is not a rvalue reference to the template paremeter `T`, but `std::vector<T>`. So `v` is "just" an rvalue reference and then can't be bound to an lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by the accepted answer:

> **the vector is not considered as Forwarding Reference (aka Universal Reference).**

(Compiler knows that it is a vector, thus no template reference deduction for this part, which means that the double ampersand -- **&&** -- is treated as rvalue reference to a vector of unknown type T).

### But if we do want to treat a vector as Forwarding Reference?

In case you do wish to pass a vector as a Forwarding Reference you can do something like that:

```
template<typename T> struct is_vector : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : public std::true_type {};

// [1] the special case
// the vector becomes now just V and acts as Forwarding Reference
// the enable_if ensures that we deal with V that is a vector
template<typename V, typename ...Args>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_vector<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<V>>>::value
>::type
f(V&& v, Args&& ...args) {
    std::cout << "f taking a vector + parameter pack\n";
}

// [2] the generic case
template<typename ...Args>
void f(Args&& ...args) {
    std::cout << "f taking a parameter pack\n";
}

int main() {
    // all cases below go to the 1st overload
    std::vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3};
    f(v1, 3);

    const std::vector<int> v2{1, 2, 3};
    f(v2, 3);

    f(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}, 3);

    // this goes to the 2nd overload
    std::array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
    f(a, 3);
}
```